# MaskedTextBox - How put IBeam at the end, even if the user click anywhere?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MaskedTextBox and I want to put the IBeam cursor at the end(or beginning) of the box.

Example:

[image: IBeam Cursor at position 3]

-User click in the MaskedTextBox and start to type, but he need to "backspace" because he clicked in the middle of the box, how can I move the cursor automatically to the left/right?

MaskedTextBox "Cod IBGE" is "000" (3 numbers required)

[image: Now IBeam cursor at position 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add "Enter" event on MaskedTextBox 
then put below code to set home:

```
mtb.SelStart = 0;
mtb.SelLength = 0;
```

Comment: Worked using Click event. Thanks. :D